# Timer in my app; delay in between commands

Tags: ios, timer, delay, wait

Okay, so I am making an app somewhat similar to flappy bird, but instead using a helicopter and a tap and hold mechanic instead of a tap, first of all when I press and hold I have the helicopter file a picture of the helicopter going up, and when I let go, I have the file a picture of it going down.  To make it more look fluid I want to create an animation of just simply shifting the helicopter up/down about 10 degrees every .05ish seconds, how would I right a timer to be able to do this. This is the command that switches the image file:

```
Heli.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"HeliUp.png"];
```

or

```
Heli.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Helidown.png"];
```

Basically I want this:

```
Heli.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"HeliUp1.png"];
(wait .05 seconds)
Heli.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Heli2.png"];
(wait .05 seconds)
Heli.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"HeliUp5.png"];
```

Something along the lines of that, however I know you need to use a timer with intervals and such..

SECOND of all, how would I make it so that I only can move the helicopter up and down when this animation isn't going on, so it doesn't look stupid.

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, the animation is straight-forward enough that you can handle it all within the `UIImageView`:

```
Heli.image = normalImage;
Heli.animationImages = @[ normalImage, upImage, normalImage, downImage ];
Heli.animationDuration = 4 * .05;
Heli.animationRepeatCount = 0;
```

To stop the animation just set `animationImages` to nil, to restart the animation reset `animationImages = @[ ... ]`

When you assign an array of images to animationImages, the images will be cycled through at a rate determined by animationDuration.  If you subsequently assign nil to animationImages, then the the image property will be used to determine what is displayed.  So, by assigning either nil or the array `@[ normalImage, upImage, normalImage, downImage ]` you can turn animation on and off.

Comment: Thanks a lot!
When you said:
    animationImages = @[...]
do you just put: = @[nil] or how would I do that?  Sorry new to coding

Comment: Also, does the imageview stay on the last image of the animation or can I just put:

Heli.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"HeliDown.png"];

Comment: Hopefully the edits answer your question.  I'm kind of assuming that when the copter is moving up or down you want it in the normal position.

Comment: Can I email you somewhere where I can go into detail?  I tried this but it didn't work

Comment: The bottom line is you can easily animate a UIImageView with a sequence of images like you're wanting to do.  The exact details of the images and sequences I leave to your imagination :)